# Как понять, пассивный обработчик событий

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

Вот есть код, если докрутить до конца TEXTAREA то будет вылелать ошибка в консоли, https://codepen.io/mihail-nezemnoy/pen/vwQaZK

```html
document.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName != 'TEXTAREA') return;
  var area = e.target;

  var delta = e.deltaY || e.detail || e.wheelDelta;

  if (delta < 0 && area.scrollTop == 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  if (delta > 0 && area.scrollHeight - area.clientHeight - area.scrollTop <= 1) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

Как я понимаю, это связанно с пассивным обработчиком, а чтто это такое не могу понять, и в нете нашел решение проблеммы путем добавлления {passive : false}, но тоже не понимаю что это делает

Answer (score 4, accepted):

у слушателя событий есть опция `passive`, которая `указывает, что слушатель никогда не вызовет preventDefault(). Если все же вызов будет произведен, браузер должен игнорировать его и генерировать консольное предупреждение.`
Так вот по умолчанию её значение `false`, но для событий прокрутки `wheel/mousewheel`, которые добавлены на уровне документа `window.document\window.document.body\window` её значение по умолчанию равно true, что и генерирует предупреждение в консоли.

Связано это с улучшением производительности прокрутки - вот тут об этом подробнее https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/06/passive-event-listeners

В вашем случае можно сразу повесить событие на `textarea`, а не `document`, т.к. вы всё равно выполняете действие только, если событие происходит на `textarea`

Comment: Спасибо, стало понятно!

Comment: @MenLand Если ответ вам помог - приймите его как верный, нажав на галочку под количеством голосов.